# Do I need to recheck in baggage in PVG?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, china, pvg

I’m flying on China Eastern JFK-PVG-ICN. My flights are on the same ticket. Will my baggage be checked through all the way from JFK to ICN or do I have to claim and recheck in my baggage at PVG? If I do need to recheck it at PVG, what is the process like? Where do I go and do I need a visa?

Answer (score 1):

**You do not need to claim your bags at PVG**, they will be checked straight through to ICN.

[You also do not need a visa](https://www.travelchinaguide.com/tour/visa/free-transit-144-hours.htm), assuming you're an American citizen, your connection is less than 24 hours and you plan to stay within the airport.